# spark Failed to get block(s) error

Tags: apache-spark

I run a very large job with spark. I got error like

```
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18444_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18504_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18692_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18779_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18818_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18877_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_18923_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_19109_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_19125_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from bhdp4005.prod.bdd.jp.local:53161
15/07/15 18:58:17 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Failed to fetch block shuffle_7_19312_7412, and will not retry (0 retries)
```

I don't know what cause this kind of error.
I am using Spark 1.4.0
with environment:
--driver-memory 60G --num-executors 130 --master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 45G

Answer (score 1):

ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator failed to fetch exception is noticed when a running executor tries accessing a block which is no more available. This can be because the previous executor got killed or the block is now inaccessible.